# APNS result legend

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications

Does anyone knows what does int return values for APNS send push messages mean.

To be more specific, here is my PHP server side directive:

```
$res = fwrite($apns, $apnsMessage);
```

Sometimes $res is 169, sometimes some other number. Has anyone deciphered this?

Regardz,
Mladen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php):

> fwrite() returns the number of bytes
>   written, or FALSE on error.

So `$res` contains the bytes from `$apnsMessage` that were written or just FALSE.